# How to make the category itself in the Parent Category and not just the id

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework for API and I wrote the model Category in which I have parent and I'm using it like this: `parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)`
In API it looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 7,
    "name": "softwares",
    "img": "",
    "parent": 1
},
{
    "id": 8,
    "name": "databases",
    "img": "",
    "parent": 1
},
{
    "id": 9,
    "name": "appearance",
    "img": "",
    "parent": 2
},
{
    "id": 10,
    "name": "media",
    "img": "",
    "parent": 2
},
{
    "id": 11,
    "name": "system",
    "img": "",
    "parent": 2
},
```

Here is Category Serializer:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'
```

And Category View Set:

```
class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer

    action_to_serializer = {
        "retrieve": CategoryDetailSerializer,
    }

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return self.action_to_serializer.get(
            self.action,
            self.serializer_class
        )
```

How can I make the category itself and not just the id?

Comment: Are you wanting `"id"` to be `"category` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you won't be handling with an infinite sequence of relations and are handling this with just one level of parenting, you can achieve that by using [`nested serializers`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships), an example on your scenario would be something like this:

```
class NestedCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'img')

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parent = NestedCategorySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'
```

If your relationship needs more depth levels, you can improve this example to include always the serialized parent - be careful with cycles.